# HAProxy routes requests to wrong server

Tags: haproxy

We are using HAProxy for our app. We have a separate server for site, API, docs and blog.
We have following HAproxy configurations

```
frontend http
  mode http
  bind *:80

  redirect prefix https://www.kbook.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i kbook.com }
  redirect scheme https code 301 if { hdr(host) -i www.kbook.com } !{ ssl_fc }
  redirect scheme https code 301 if { hdr(host) -i docs.kbook.com } !{ ssl_fc }
  redirect scheme https code 301 if { hdr(host) -i api.kbook.com } !{ ssl_fc }

  acl www       hdr(host) -i www.kbook.com
  acl docs      hdr(host) -i docs.kbook.com
  acl api       hdr(host) -i api.kbook.com
  acl blog      path -i -m beg /blog

  use_backend blog_server if www blog
  use_backend site_server if www
  use_backend api_server if api
  use_backend docs_server if docs


frontend https
  mode http
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/live/wildcard_kbook.pem alpn h2,http/1.1

  redirect prefix https://www.kbook.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i kbook.com }

  use_backend blog_server if { ssl_fc_sni -i www.kbook.com } { path -i -m beg /blog }
  use_backend site_server if { ssl_fc_sni -i www.kbook.com }
  use_backend api_server if { ssl_fc_sni -i api.kbook.com }
  use_backend docs_server if { ssl_fc_sni -i docs.kbook.com }
```

HAProxy Version: **2.2.0-1ppa1~bionic**

**Issue:**

When we access the site ([www.kbook.com](http://www.kbook.com)), it works sometimes. Sometimes it goes to blog server, says 404 not found. I expect "www.kbook.com" should always go to the site server.
This happens even to docs and API requests. Those requests are also going to the blog server sometimes.

HAproxy directs the requests to the wrong server. Why does it happen? is there any issue with configurations?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in 2.2.0 and it should be fixed in 2.2.1

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a link to real bug?